# Bootstrap collapse with fixed positioning

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap button that, when clicked, brings up a div that starts from the top of the page. It's a refine search menu. This div has a bar on top (refine header) that I'd like to keep fixed even though the user scrolls down. The rest of that div (refine menu) should be scrollable yet be ON TOP of the actual web page. Right now, the refine menu is merged with the page. If I scroll the page up, the refine menu tucks underneath the refine header.

In the following picture you can see it starts off ok as in the left picture. But when I move the page up, the menu is header beneath the refine header as in the right picture.

[image]

Here is a [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/M3aMzQ0bnf). As you can see, when you scroll all the way down and click the trigger button, you don't even see the refine menu until you scroll all the way up!

Also, here is the relevant code for this part of my interface:

```css
#mobile-filter-trigger {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 10px 12px;
}
#refine-header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10000;
  background-color: #27402a;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 6px 15px;
}
#refine-header .btn-default {
  width: 50%;
}
#refine-header > .row > div:first-child {
  padding-top: 7px;
}
#refine-mobile.collapsing {
  z-index: 10000;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
#refine-mobile.collapse.in {
  display: block;
  z-index: 10000;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
#refine-accordion .panel-heading {
  padding: 10px 10px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 0;
}
#refine-accordion .panel+.panel {
  margin-top: 0;
  border-top: none;
}
#refine-accordion .panel {
  border-radius: 0;
}
#refine-accordion .list-unstyled {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
#refine-accordion .list-unstyled li+li {
  margin-top: 8px;
}
#refine-accordion {
  margin: 45px -15px 0 -15px;
}
#refine-mobile {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 4px -2px #828181;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 4px 4px -2px #828181;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 4px 4px -2px #828181;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1000000;
}
#refine-accordion .panel-title a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<div id="mobile-filters">
  <!--Mobile Filters -->
  <div class="col-xs-12 no-side-padding">
    <a id="mobile-filter-trigger" role="button" class="btn btn-block btn-default" data-toggle="collapse" href="#refine-mobile">Filter by</a>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse" id="refine-mobile">
    <div id="refine-header" class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
          <strong>FILTER:</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-7 text-right">
          <a href="#" class="btn link" style="color:#fff; text-decoration:underline">Clear</a>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Apply</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 text-right">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#refine-mobile" style="font-size:150%; padding:0; color:#fff;"><i class="ion-close-round"></i>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="panel-group" id="refine-accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading" role="tab">
            <div class="panel-title">
              <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#refine-accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne" class="btn-block">
              Size
              <span class="ion-plus"></span></a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel">
            <div class="panel-body">
              <ul class="list-unstyled">
                <!-- [Option list...] -->
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- [Additional filters...] -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--/Mobile Filters -->
</div>
```

Comment: You have a div with the class of `col-xs-12` containing the entire dropdown - what happens if you add `position: fixed;` to that?

Comment: @Toby as I wrote in a comment to Serlite, this prevents me from being able to scroll the menu should it become longer than the screen height.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that while your header is `position:fixed`, the accordion contents are still within a container that is `position:absolute`. You can solve this problem by just changing the `position` values in a couple of your style declaration blocks:

```css
#refine-mobile {
    position: fixed; /* from absolute */
}

#refine-header {
    position: absolute; /* from fixed */
}
```

EDIT: To allow accordion items to be scrolled through when vertical screen space is insufficient to display them all, you'll also need to add the following styles to `#refine-accordion`:

```css
#refine-accordion {
    max-height: calc(100vh - 45px); /* The 45px is not random, it's the margin-top */
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Here's an [updated Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/Huu7xA060V). Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I forgot to say that I did try this. The problem is that when the menu opens really long, I can't scroll if it goes past the screen ;)

Comment: @RachelS I see! Hmmm, I think a bit more tweaking to the CSS should be able to fix that (see my edit).

Comment: This is much better. The only problem now is that scrolling (with my finger) upward on the screen to push content down, is causing the accordions to snap shut. Sometimes. I'm trying to figure out when it's happening and when not.

Comment: @RachelS Hmmm, that's a problematic usability issue, though I wonder how it can be addressed. Does this happen every time you attempt to scroll? Unfortunately, I can't test this outside of desktop Chrome's emulation, and it works fine there. You could consider adding open/close buttons to the accordion items, rather than making the entire item clickable - this provides more space to touch and scroll without interacting with them. (Though this will require a bit more than just a CSS fix at that point.)

Comment: I made the entire panel header clickable because that's what my client wanted. We'll see if it causes issues. If it does, I'll do as you suggest. 

But I really appreciate your help with this since it's been bugging me for a while and you solved the css :)

Comment: @RachelS Well, I'm glad I could help you out at least partially! Hopefully your client isn't too picky if you do need to change it. =P